# baffled by python __str__ method and unicode behaviour

Tags: python, django, unicode

This is Python 2.7. Don't judge me. :)

I have a Django application where the class file is being used for a bit of auditing. For historical reasons I have a `__str__` method in this class, and I am trying to return something useful.

```
   def __str__(self):
      return "%s %s" % (self.guid, self.setside_username)
```

Now, this failed with non-ascii characters in the setside_username, as the audit log was indirectly calling `__str__` like so

```
log.info("change to %s", obj)
```

I tried renaming `__str__` to `__unicode__` but it still failed in the same location. So I tried sanitize the string by ascii encoding it and having the encoder replace anything it didn't understand.

```
def __str__(self):
   return "%s %s" % (self.guid, self.setside_username.encode('ascii', 'replace')
```

but that line fails with a UnicodeDecodeError, which baffles me because I thought that call would tell the encoder to replace anything it doesn't understand.

So to prove that I don't understand the difference between encode() and decode(), I s/encode/decode and suddenly the error is gone.

And I haven't a clue why. I thought decode created unicode objects and encode created byte strings, so why would decode on a unicode object help here?

Worse, my little test script that simply prints the object using a print statement is now failing!

```
    username = self.setside_username.decode('ascii', 'replace')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So I fix one use case but break another.

I need to understand this to know that I'm actually fixing the problem and not just playing whack-a-mole until the backtraces go away.

Help appreciated.

Update: Moving to `__unicode__` methods that return unicode.

Still seeing this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 784, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 662, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 444, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/logging/__init__.py", line 314, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
  File "/etc/e-smith/web/django/teleworker/clients/models.py", line 364, in __unicode__
    return u"%s %s" % (self.guid, self.setside_username)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
[03/Aug/2017 12:59:03.907] ERROR [MainThread] [tug-eventd.tug-eventd:1727] Error handling cluster event: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Required reading: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/unicode/#choosing-between-str-and-unicode. *Django’s Model base class automatically provides a __str__() implementation that calls __unicode__() and encodes the result into UTF-8.*.

Comment: You can try the `unidecode` module, you can also prefix your template string with "u" (u"%s %s").

Comment: @PauloScardine: absolutely no need to `unidecode`; all that is required is making sure that `__unicode__` actually returns *unicode data*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know nothing about the OP needs, just mentioned unidecode as robust alternative to `.encode('ascii', 'replace')`.

Comment: @PauloScardine: they are not encoding though, they tried to **decode** the Unicode username; but that includes an implicit *encode* first to bytes (otherwise there is nothing to decode, right?), and it is that encode step that fails..

Comment: You are right as always, I'm just a last-word freak. :-)

Comment: I don't see why .encode('ascii', 'replace') would not be robust. If it hits anything non-ascii, it should replace it, yes?

Comment: It seems like the format operation is forcing an ascii codec, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @MichaelSoulier: `str.encode()` triggers an implicit *decode*. If you have UTF-8 bytestrings, (say `'\xc3\x9cn\xc3\xaec\xc3\xb3d\xc3\xa6'`), then the implicit decode will fail.

Comment: @MichaelSoulier: but you already *have* a bytestring, so encoding makes no sense there. This is why Python 3 has removed `bytes.encode()` altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your model a `__unicode__` method that *actually returns Unicode*:

```
def __unicode__(self):
   return u"%s %s" % (self.guid, self.setside_username)
```

Note the `u` prefix, we used a Unicode literal, and we did not encode the username.

The Django model baseclass [provides a `__str__` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/unicode/#choosing-between-str-and-unicode) that'll take the `__unicode__` output and encode it to a bytestring for you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @MichaelSoulier: so what happens instead? Do you have a full traceback? Do make sure you don't have a `__str__` method defined that overrides the base method.

Comment: @MichaelSoulier: what are the *values* of those two fields. One of them is *not a unicode object* and can't be decoded as ASCII. Is `guid` a bytestring? You'll have to decode that value to be a valid Unicode value if it is.

Comment: Backtrace above, hard to paste in a comment. Both fields are Django CharFields storing unicode in postgres. I'll double check the type at runtime, and try individual format strings to confirm that the problem is the setside_username and not the guid.

Comment: ah, no. The Django CharField is giving me a string, therefore it's encoded, and I need to decode to a unicode object. Testing...

Comment: Yes, that worked. So postgres is storing UTF-8, which makes sense, and the Django ORM is not giving me Unicode objects back, I must decode them myself. Got it.

Comment: Wait no, the ORM is giving me unicode but I'm setting it as UTF-8. That's the inconsistency I was missing. I'm going to go bang my head on my table for a while now.